# Is there a name for this type of sentence: "The higher the temperature, the higher the pressure"?

Tags: expressions, terminology, syntactic-analysis, sentence-patterns

Is there a name for this type of sentence: "The higher the temperature, the higher the pressure"?

Such a word grouping is generally accepted as a sentence in science.

Comment: I should call it a correlative sentence, although English accomplishes this kind of thing without the use of any dedicated correlative conjunction such as the German *je . . . desto.* After all, a correlation is precisely what is being asserted here.

Comment: I would call it a conclusion resulting from the [ideal gas law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas_law).

Comment: @WBT The question is about the English language :)

Comment: @Kris that's why it's a comment, not an answer...but it's still what I would call it when trying to express it in English ;-).

Comment: The question has nothing to do with physics, incidentally. We are discussing the sentence pattern with a typical example. HTH.

Comment: For a more tuneful example, try this from [Jimmy Cliff](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Znh0OM9jiA).

Comment: http://grammar.about.com/od/c/g/Comparative-Correlatives.htm  --  comparative correlative - definition and examples of ...

Comment: It's surprising this has not been dealt with so far on this site, or is it?

Comment: @FumbleFingers That post doesn't provide the name, correct definition and details, it's no help here. Maybe the questions should be merged.

Comment: @Kris: Or Brian (and now as I write, rogermue) could copy their answers here into the original. I really don't think we should retain two separate questions about the same construction. The only real difference is one asks *Is this construction a valid sentence? If not, what is it [called]?* where the other one simply asks *What is this construction called?*. The fact that no-one explicitly covered the "follow-on" Q on the first post is something that should be addressed there (albeit belatedly), not here. The site is sprawling enough as it is.

Comment: There's also the unspoken question "Is this a sentence (since there's no subject _or_ verb)?"

Comment: @Mitch "Hi Mitch!" **is** a sentence. See relevant posts on this same site.

Comment: @Kris But I could choose a different definition and say '"Hi Mitch!" is not a sentence'. It's naughty when opinions are stated out as if they were gospel.

Comment: @WBT I thought it was Boyle's Law!  Maybe that's volume and temperature...?

Answer (score 6):

There are several names for it listed in a page on the subject [here](http://grammar.about.com/od/c/g/Comparative-Correlatives.htm), which favors the term ***comparative correlative,*** since it asserts *correlation* by using *comparative* forms of two adjectives:

> The comparative correlative is also known as the *correlative construction,* the *conditional comparative,* or the *“the . . . the”* construction.

For a a contribution to and brief bibliography of linguistic scholarship on this construction (as of 2004), see [Robert D. Borsley, “An Approach to English Comparative
Correlatives.”](http://csli-publications.stanford.edu/HPSG/5/borsley.pdf)

Comment: Thank you. This question has been nagging me for years. It appears that your source favors inserting the verb into the second clause, as opposed to leaving it implied.

Answer (score 4):

This grammatical structure should have a name, but of course, in grammars it often goes without any name. You can't even be sure where in a grammar you will find it. I just had a look at Longman English Grammar and looked through the chapter Adjectives, comparisons, but found nothing. In the register I found it under the: the ... the (clauses of comparison).

If you search this structure on the Internet you can google for something like "the sooner the better" and you will find some web sides.

As to a name, there seems to be no standard name and you can find various labels. A mathematician woud say it describes a proportional relation , so one might say comparisons containing a proportional relation. But of course, that is no name. "The-the construction" would do the job, I think, as you find something in registers of grammars under "the ...the".

The particles the + comparative are a kind of correlatives. But you find such a chapter only in Latin Grammars. In most English grammars this term is not even in the register. "The" in this comparative structure is not identical to the normal definite article. Historically this the is from a vanished fifth case of the definite article.

It should be known how  Latin expressed the idea of proportionality. They had no ready-made function words and had to explain it in common words. They said: Something is in that measure more expensive in which measure it is better. And soon the could say it a bit shorter eo modo ... quo modo or
eo ... quo. English expressed it with "in that measure ... in that measure and reduced it to "thè ...thè" (thè marks the different origin from an old fifth case form).